# How to Compare nullable objects

Tags: asp.net, nullable

I need to compare a current List of Objects from a DB against a new List of Objects.  I want to compare them and highlight for the user those which have changed (in this case, return TRUE that they are different).

Since some of my objects are Nullable, this involves a lot of IF NOT IS Nothing on the side of the NewObj and the CurrentObj...I've trying to find a more efficient way of writing the below as I have to use it to compare about 30 objects of different types, IE Date, Decimal, Int, etc..

The below works until say either of the Obj has no Rank and is therefore Nothing

Suggestions?

```
Dim Rank As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "Rank")
Dim Regiment As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "Rank")
Dim DateofBirth As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "DoB")

Private Function CompareData(NewObj As Business.Casualty, CurrentObj As Business.Casualty, FieldToComapre As String) As Boolean

Select Case FieldToComapre
        Case "DateOfBirth"
            Return (Nullable.Equals(NewCasualty.DateOfBirth, CurrentCasualty.DateOfBirth))
        Case "Age"
            Return (Nullable.Equals(NewCasualty.Age, CurrentCasualty.Age))            
        Case "Rank"
            Return (Nullable.Equals(NewCasualty.Rank.ID, CurrentCasualty.Rank.ID))
        Case "Regiment"
            Return (Nullable.Equals(NewCasualty.Regiment.ID, CurrentCasualty.Regiment.ID))           
        Case Else
            Return True
    End Select

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up just going with an Extension method..it was simpler and cleaner IMO.

```
Dim Rank As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "Rank")
Dim Regiment As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "Regiment")
Dim Trade As Boolean = CompareData(NewObj, CurrentObj, "Trade")

Private Function CompareData(NewObj As Business.Casualty, CurrentObj As Business.Casualty, FieldToComapre As String) As Boolean

 Select Case FieldToComapre
        Case "Trade"
            Return NewCasualty.Trade.NullableEquals(CurrentCasualty.Trade)
        Case "Rank"
            Return NewCasualty.Rank.NullableEquals(CurrentCasualty.Rank)
        Case "Regiment"
            Return NewCasualty.Regiment.NullableEquals(CurrentCasualty.Regiment)                     
    Case Else
        Return True
End Select

End Function

public static class NullableCompare 
{
    public static bool NullableEquals<T>(this T s1, T s2)
                               where T : class
    {
        if (s1 == null)
        {
            return s2 == null;
        }

        return s1.Equals(s2);
    }

}
public partial class Rank 
{
public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p2 = obj as Rank;

        if (p2 == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (this.ID != p2.ID)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return this.ID == p2.ID;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.ID.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion is to change the name of your function to something like AreFieldValuesTheSame.  My second suggestion is to negate the purpose of the function.  In other words, return True when the values are the same.

If you follow my first two suggestions, then for each one of your cases, instead of simply

```
Return (Nullable.Equals(a.ID, b.ID))
```

you need something more like

```
Return ((a Is Nothing And b Is Nothing) Or (a.ID Is Nothing And b.ID Is Nothing) Or (Nullable.Equals(a.ID, b.ID)))
```

For example, a represents NewCasualty.Rank and b represents CurrentCasualty.Rank.  You need to check for the object being Nothing (null in other words) before you try to check properties of the object.

Also, at the beginning of the function, you need to check whether NewObj Is Nothing and whether CurrentObj Is Nothing:

```
If (NewObj Is Nothing) And (CurrentObj Is Nothing) Then
    Return True
Else If (NewObj Is Nothing) Or (CurrentObj Is Nothing)
    Return False
```

Please forgive me if my VB syntax is not perfect. (I'm much more fluent in C#.)